# getting periodically network provider updates within certain intervals

Tags: android

my target is to get periodically location updates from network provider using requestlocationupdate() method during certain intervals(x sec), then execute LocationManager.removeUpdates() method to remove updates and achieve an power consumption to be as minimum as possible,

the problem which faced me is the requestlocationupdate() method invoked and call onlocationchanged method  every 45 sec, even its "mintime" (2nd parameter in this method) is less than 45 !!, why this happen?

also, the 2nd problem is during each interval,  i need to invoke the requestlocationupdates method and records the current latitude and longitude of the user's location and compare it with the recorded latitude and longitude of the last location, if its the same(user still stationary), display "your last location is ...", if happen an change in the location, display "your updated location is ...."  .
how i can do it ?

i tried to solve this problem using use handler.post(myRunnable) and calling an runnable object with timertask class to execute requestlocationupdates() method every (x sec) which determined in timertask input parameters.

when i tested this code, its get the latitude and longitude every x sec but its recorded values are changes even i still in the same location!

also,is writing any code in onlocationchanged() override method represents a good approach from side of energy saving?

also, can you tell me how i can get the accuracy of any network provider (wifi/ 3G)?

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Code is looks like:

intializations:

```
Timer t1;
Timer t2;
TimerTask mTimerTask1;
TimerTask  mTimerTask2;
Handler hand;
Handler hand1;
public LocationManager locationManager;
// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude
double Altitude; // longitude
double accuracy; // accuracy


// The minimum distance to change notifications Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 0 meters

// The minimum time between notifications updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 10; // 10 sec
```

Handler part:

```
 Runnable run1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        mTimerTask1 = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                hand.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if(check_conectivity()){
                            //flag1=false;
                            get_location();
                            time++;
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        };
t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTimerTask1, 0, 10000);

    }
};
```

check_connectivity method:

```
public boolean check_conectivity(){


    // put the reference LocationManger
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // getting network status
    // isProviderEnabled ==> Returns the current enabled/disabled status of the NETWORK_PROVIDERr.
    //  If the user has enabled this provider in the Settings menu, true is returned otherwise false is returned
    isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if ( !isNetworkEnabled) {
        // no network provider is enabled
        showSettingsAlert();
        return false;

    } 
    else{

        return true;
    }

}
```

get_location method:

```
public void get_location(){

                    if (isNetworkEnabled) {

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
    Log.d("Network", "Network");
```

onlocationchanged() override method:

```
if (locationManager!= null){

    location = locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        tv2.setText("Your last Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude );
        tv3.setText("Last estimeted location number : " + time1);
        time1++;
        stopUpdating();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can you tell me how i can get the accuracy of any network provider (wifi/ 3G)

As I know you can't. But you can filter responses and tell to device to notify you only if accuracy is ..... .

1st off you can use `postDelayed` instead `post`:

```
private int mSampleDurationTime = 10000; // 10 sec for example 
...    
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, mSampleDurationTime);`
```

2nd you can try to get "best location" described in one of my answers, see link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android/12963889#12963889)

hope it will help you,

Comment: if i want to get network provider accuracy, can i use location.getAccuracy()?

is it benefit ?

Comment: sure, `getAccuracy` returns you value in meters. if accuracy for example 10, it means that GPS with 95% guesses your location in radius of 10 meters.

Comment: this is right for GPS, but for Networkprovider, i get accuracy value equal to 45 or 50, is this means that networksprovider with 68% guesses my location in radius of 45 meter?

Comment: for indoor its ok, GPS provider has better accuracy

Comment: but GPS is battery hunger and getting low accuarcy in indoor env. and my target is to get  indoor location, thus the networks location based (wi-fi) is more better?